# $a \in (0, 1)$, Borel subset $A$ of $[-1, 1]$ where $\lim_{r \to 0+} {{m(A \cap [-r, r])}\over{2r}} = a$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $a \in (0, 1)$. What is a Borel subset $A$ of $[-1, 1]$ where$$\lim_{r \to 0+} {{m(A \cap [-r, r])}\over{2r}} = a?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=A^-\cup A^+,$ where $A^+=\cup_{n=1}^\infty [1/(n+1),1/(n+1)+a(1/n-1/(n+1))),$ i.e., take the left $a$ of each interval $[1/n,1/(n+1))$, and $A^-=-A=\{-x\mid x\in A^+\}$. $A$ is borel being a countable union of intervals, and for any $r=1/k\le 1$,

$$
m(A\cap[-r,r])=2\sum_{n=k}^\infty a(1/n-1/(n+1))=2a/k.
$$

Then for any $r\in [1/(k+1),1/k],$

$$ (2r)^{-1}m(A\cap[-r,r])\le (2/(k+1))^{-1}m(A\cap[-1/k,1/k])=a(k+1)/k,$$
and 
$$ (2r)^{-1}m(A\cap[-r,r])\ge (2/k)^{-1}m(A\cap[-1/(k+1),1/(k+1)])=ak/(k+1),$$

errors that vanish as $r\to 0^+$.